# How do i change the direction and rotation of rotataion axis?

Tags: axis

I have this model and i want it to the handler to spin in the direction that the cursor is so the handler can turn how its should be[image], how can i do it?

Comment: May be Press R and then Z!

Comment: No, i want to rotate the rotation axis like my 3d cursor is

Comment: According to me, that can't change actually

Comment: What i wanted was to rotate the handler with the inclination of the cursor in order to rotate like it was attached to the rest of the bike, if i just simply rotate it it will rotate in a 90 degree angle...

Comment: do you know how i caqn do this?

Comment: I think you should change the pivot point of the handle!

Answer (score 0):

You could parent the handle to a bone. You could also bring your object back to a vertical position (aligned with X, Y and Z), parent it to an empty (to make this empty is now its new global reference instead of the world) then tilt the empty. Now you can make the object rotate on its own axis for example with <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for your help i will keep that in mind when export the model to unreal engine, since that is the final porpouse :)